# How can I stop the kde-telepathy UI from appearing under Unity when I use the messaging menu?

Tags: empathy, telepathy, kde-telepathy

KDE Telepathy keeps getting in the way every time I try to use Empathy from the messaging menu. If I get a message, it opens in the KDE telepathy UI instead of in Empathy. This is rather frustrating as it causes a delay before it opens, and is not integrated with Empathy.

How can I stop this from happening? This still happens in 12.10 and I've had to remove the kde-telepathy packages. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out how to do this (Ubuntu 12.10):

Edit `/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Telepathy.Client.KTp.TextUi.service` to comment out (or remove) the link to `ktp-text-ui` and use `Empathy` instead.

In the end, the service file will look like this:

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.freedesktop.Telepathy.Client.KTp.TextUi
# Exec=/usr/lib/kde4/libexec/ktp-text-ui
Exec=/usr/lib/empathy/empathy-chat
```

After this, I figured I had to restart dbus, but doing a

```
sudo service dbus restart
```

is evidently a bad idea, since it locks up everything.

So I suppose you have to log out and log back in (or reboot, which is what I ended up having to do).

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug report on this issue here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ktp-text-ui/+bug/951104
There's a proposed solution on the last line, but I have to confess that I'm not entirely sure how to go about defining a preferred handler on dbus.
(Since it's easy enough to remove the kde-telepathy packages without affecting the rest of KDE and I don't need two messaging clients, I just went with that option instead.)